# Matrix to the power of a matrix

Tags: matrices

If A=$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & a & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & a \\
  \end{bmatrix}$ and B=$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    b & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & b & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & b \\
  \end{bmatrix}$ then what is $A^B$

I know what A+B is and I know what A*B is. I even know what $e^A$ is but I was wondering what $A^B$ would be. Does it even have any meaning?

$a^b = (e^{\ln a})^b = e^{b \cdot\ln a}$

So I assume that

$A^B = (e^{\ln A})^B = e^{B \cdot\ln A}$

If so then the question becomes what is the natural log of A?

Comment: Do you know what the notation $A^{B}$ means? Have you seen any worked examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a>0$, then 
$$
\ln{A}:= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\ln{a} & & \\
 & \ln{a} & \\
 & & \ln{a}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Given that $a^b := e^{b\ln{a}}$, a natural definition is
$$
A^B:=e^{B\ln{A}},
$$
where
$$
e^X:= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{X^k}{k!}.
$$

In this case, since the matrices are diagonal, it follows that
$$
A^B = e^{B \ln{A}}
= \begin{bmatrix}
e^{b\ln{a}} & & \\
 & e^{b\ln{a}} & \\
 & & e^{b\ln{a}}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
a^{b} & & \\
 & a^{b} & \\
 & & a^{b}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$